# httppost.execute goes to exception

Tags: android, http-post

i have searched each and every thing at this site but still i don't understand what is matter with my code i have debugged it also it goes to exception when it tries to execute the this line "HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost)" i have also added permission of internet in android manifest file but still don't understand whats the matter.

please help me i shall be very thankful to all of you.....

here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         // set a click listener on the alert button
        Button alert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alertbtn);
        alert.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

public void onClick(View view) 
    {

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.alertbtn)) 
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","awais"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password","123"));

        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://localhost/doctroidlogin.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

            if(entity.toString().length()>0)
            alertbox.setMessage("Welcome to DangerZone!");
            else
                alertbox.setMessage("Invalid Email or Password");   


            alertbox.show();        
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Log Cat

```
09-23 00:53:51.251: WARN/System.err(327): java.net.UnknownHostException: pannl.com
09-23 00:53:51.266: WARN/System.err(327):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
09-23 00:53:51.285: WARN/System.err(327):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
09-23 00:53:51.285: WARN/System.err(327):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
09-23 00:53:51.306: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
09-23 00:53:51.316: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-23 00:53:51.336: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-23 00:53:51.356: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
09-23 00:53:51.366: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-23 00:53:51.375: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-23 00:53:51.386: WARN/System.err(327):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-23 00:53:51.406: WARN/System.err(327):     at huuah.dialogboxes.LastActivity.onClick(LastActivity.java:57)
09-23 00:53:51.415: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-23 00:53:51.436: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-23 00:53:51.466: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-23 00:53:51.476: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 00:53:51.486: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-23 00:53:51.506: WARN/System.err(327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-23 00:53:51.516: WARN/System.err(327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 00:53:51.526: WARN/System.err(327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-23 00:53:51.546: WARN/System.err(327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-23 00:53:51.566: WARN/System.err(327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-23 00:53:51.566: WARN/System.err(327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the exception and stack trace.  In most cases it's almost immediately obvious what's going on when you see the Exception and StackTrace

Comment: Rich how can i see the exception or stack trace, i don't know but when it goes in the exception, logcat show two lines "input event dispatching timed out" and "application is not responding"

Comment: UnknownHostException - I guess your emulator does not have net access or DNS is not working.

Comment: i have run the browser it has internet access and DNS is working fine

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost` implies that you are running server on your device (or emulator). Are you? I guess not since it's php.

You have to use a real IP or domain name of the server.

OTOH if you are trying this on emulator and server is on your host machne then you need to set a few parameters: http://juristr.com/blog/2009/10/accessing-host-machine-from-your/

Comment: m yes m running wamp server and have a webservice code in php

Comment: `localhost` means the emulator virtual machine, not the host machne. Read the link I provided.

Comment: i have also given this HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://pannl.com/doctroidlogin.php"); but still it goes into exception

Comment: Does emulator have internet connection? Use browser in emulator to check it.

Comment: Also, what kind of exception are you getting? Post logcat please.